# How can I run a formula in a sql server (Mysql or PostgreSQL, EST) on update like Quickbase?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql

I have a PHP/MariaDB(MySQL) Program that does a lot of math equations throughout the day. Right now PHP is doing all of my math for me and updating the mysql database. This program of mine is growing a lot and I am needing a better solution to run these 'equations/formulas'. I have looked into Stored Procedures and Triggers but have found flaws with both on MySQL and they are very Time consuming. I looked into QuickBase and seem to like where they have it setup But I need direct access to the SQL Database.

Is there a good solutions to have fields in a SQL Database update based on formulas (where there are IF, ELSE, CASE Statements ) automatically on update or insert? I am willing to try a new database if need be. I read online that QuickBase uses Microsoft SQL Server but have not found a solution that wouldn't be the same as MySQL or PortgreSQL.

Thank You for your Suggestions

Comment: for example: IF(COL_A > COL_C) COL_B = 4 ELSE COL_B = 0 ENDIF, Something like that, I know QB has their own syntax but What I am trying to ask is there a way have that run in a sql server ?

Comment: "I have looked into Stored Procedures and Triggers but have found flaws with both on MySQL and they are very Time consuming" - erm , what?

Comment: @TVarcor using **Computed Columns** is the best way for scenarios like this

Comment: I found the solution. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/virtual-columns/ - Virtual Columns. Thanks for all of the help and hints to where to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`Computed Columns`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx)(MS SQL Server):

- A computed column is a `virtual column` that `is not physically stored` in the table, unless the column is marked `PERSISTED`. A computed column expression `can use data from other columns to calculate` a value for the column to which it belongs. 
  **Example:**

  ```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Test]
  (
   [COL_A] INT NOT NULL,
   [COL_C] INT NOT NULL,
   [COL_B] as 
    CASE WHEN [COL_A]>[COL_C] 
     THEN 4
     ELSE 0
    END
  )
  ```